# Compare some date predicate based on 1st of the month

Tags: date, t-sql, datepart

I would like to get DATE format like in the title (yyyy-mm) from getdate() , in order to use it in where clause to get < and > dates from the one i formatted .So far i found almost everybody uses convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) but that's varchar and it cant be check with < and > right ? So can someone help me to make a Date in format yyyy-mm or it's impossible ?

Comment: If you have an existing datetime you should compare it against another datetime, using between for example. Why do you want to do a string comparison?

Comment: How would  you compare the `YYYY-MM` with date-time field ??

Comment: @AlexK. yep i'm making it more complex then i should , tnx everything helps :P

Comment: @YogeshSharma I thought if it's in form of Date i should be able to, but now i think there's no need for that i can do it way more simple

Comment: Perhaps the question should be rewritten to express the desire, which is not to compare to a "YYYY-MM" string, but rather, to compare some date predicate based on 1st of the month.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA done :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't VARCHAR be compared using > and < operators? So long as you have a character string in an appropriate format, you can compare it just fine. For instance, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) returns an ODBC Canonical format date, as "YYYY-MM-DD". This can obviously be compared using > and < to obtain correct results.

However, you would generally not want to do this in a database. Predicate such as this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateColumn], 120) >= '2018-02-26'
```

are considered "non-SARGable", and cannot use an index. This means that the server will apply brute force conversions to the underlying columns prior to the comparison, resulting in Index Scans or Table Scans, depending upon your schema.

For the vast majority of situations, you want the column to be used as an operand without any kind of conversion beforehand. Thus, the predicate should be expressed as:

```
WHERE [DateColumn] >= '2018-02-26'
```

This will result in an implicit cast of the '2018-02-26' operand into Date or DateTime (whatever the column type is), and this can use an index.

The absolute best would be an explicit cast such as this:

```
WHERE [DateColumn] >= CAST('2018-02-26' AS DATETIME)
```

This way, there is no room for mistakes, implicit conversions, or non-SARGable predicates.

Comment: can you help me get -7 months from this conversion CONVERT(varchar(7),GETDATE(),120) ? for day i did CONVERT(varchar(7),GETDATE()-7,120) should i do -90 or is there more accurate way ?

Comment: The standard way to get "first day of the month", in T-SQL, is to do this: DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0). Thus, 7 months prior to this would be the same expression used as an argument to DATEADD, except using MONTH. So, 7 months back from the 1st day of the current month is DATEADD(month, -7, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)). Simplify this to DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -7, 0)

Comment: the problem is i need data for last 7 days/ 7 months/7years so i'm a bit confused don't know where to start and what to do it's complex a lot , but i have to do it :P , guess firstly i need to limit dates from and to so i'm doing it with your help tnx :D

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић Yes, just define your date ranges as needed. Keep in mind that each of the ranges you are discussing start with a date, such as '2017-01-01', and do not need to be cut down to VARCHAR such as '2017-01' for any reason. You can accomplish it with DATEADD() and DATEDIFF().

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, you *do not* want to do this in the way you are asking.

To look for records that match a specific year and month, simply use two `where` criteria in this manner:

```
declare @SomeDate date = '20180114';    -- This is any date.
-- This gets the first day of the month of the date above.
declare @MonthStart date = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@SomeDate),0);
-- This gets the first day of the following month of the date above.
declare @NextMonthStart date = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@SomeDate)+1,0);

select cols
from tables
where DateCol >= @MonthStart
  and DateCol < @NextMonthStart;
```

Comment: There is no need to `select` initial values. And `declare @NextMonthStart date = dateadd( month, 1, @MonthStart );` is both simpler and clearer (IMHO).

Comment: @HABO Right you are!  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an existing datetime you should compare it against another time, using between for example. Why do you want to do a string comparison